# Ubuntu Gnome (w/ Wayland) - install desktop with X?

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, wayland, displaylink

UPDATE:  Ubuntu 18.04 is back to X with an Ubuntood version of Gnome which can be replaced with the stock version using `sudo apt install vanilla-gnome-desktop`

I have a System76 laptop with Ubuntu GNOME (17.04).  Ubuntu GNOME uses wayland.

I also have a USB DisplayLink adapter that powers 2 external monitors.
[That adapter connects but is unworkably buggy (as in no image).  Displaylink is working on wayland support but it's not ready yet.](https://github.com/DisplayLink/evdi/issues/58)

Is there a way to easily switch Ubuntu GNOME from wayland to x?

Or install an alternative desktop that uses x on the side?

Or otherwise shim some X into wayland so I can use this adapter?

I prefer Gnome, but more prefer multiple monitors with this USB displaylink, and even more prefer not reinstalling.

Thanks!

Comment: Wayland uses multiple montiors. What makes you think you need X ?

Comment: @bodhi.zazen "That adapter connects but is unworkably buggy (as in no image). Displaylink is working on wayland support but it's not ready yet."  Does Wayland support DisplayLink USB devices w/o a driver?

Comment: I do not see why not, boot a live Fedora 26 image and test it. If not, file a bug report with Fedora (IMO Fedora is most active in Wayland development although certainly other distros do as well. This is IMO a huge advantage for everyone with Ubuntu migrating to mainstream linux projects such as gnome/wayland rather than other options unique to Ubuntu).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if the same works for 17.04 as it does int 17.10, but on my 17.10, when I get to my login screen (the one with my "avatar", username, and password field, I see a small gear next to the Sign In button. When I select that gear (settings) I have a choice of easily switching between Ubuntu (which is the selection with Wayland support), Ubuntu on Xorg (which is obviously "X"), and in my case, Unity. Hope this helps.
Regards,
Richard Huelbig

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way:

1. Ubuntu 17.x is extremely buggy (in my experience). Replace with 18.04 (works stable and fine!)
2. You may look at the little gear-wheel next to the login button. If it's there it should offer different window managers.
3. Install XFCE. It is stable,  small, efficient and configurable. Just try to install the usual way on the CLI: `sudo apt-get install xfce4`
   That should do the job, then reboot and go back to 2.) and the gear-wheel.

If you love 3.) you may do the same with LXDE. Watch out for good advice with duckduckgo.

works4me on plenty of machines (old and new).

Just a remark: Wayland might be an asset having multiple monitor high res displays. Sometimes only X will do the job. Depends a lot on the environment.